# $f, G : [1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous. Find $G'(2)$ without using FTC

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, derivatives

> Let $f: [1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ and $G: [1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Where $G(x) = \int_1^{x^2} f(t)dt$  Find $G'(2)$ Using the definition of derivative ( without using FTC ).

Making a substitution $u = x^2$ then we have

$\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_1^{u+h}f(t)dt-\int_1^u f(t)dt}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0 } \frac{\int_u^{u+h}f(t)dt}{h}$

Using MVT $\exists c \in [u,u+h]$ such that $\int_u^{u+h}f(t)dt = f(c)h$

So $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_u^{u+h} f(t)}{h} = f(c)$

And now it follows that $c \to u$ so $c \to x^2$ subbing back in $x^2$ for $u$.

So it seems that $G'(2) = f(2^2) = f(4)$

I don't think this is what I want. I remember solving this problem before but can't recall what I did.

I don't remember if I make a substitution to set it up similar to proving the FTC. Feels like I am proving the derivative part of the FTC rather than solving the problem as is.

Comment: Ultimately, you will have to use some elements of the _proof_ of the FTC if you don't invoke it directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the usual approach via definition of derivative. We have $$G'(2)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\int_{1}^{(2+h)^{2}}f(t)\,dt-\int_{1}^{4}f(t)\,dt}{h}$$ and the limit above can be simplified as $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{4}^{4+4h+h^2}f(t)\,dt$$ and using mean value theorem for integrals we have $$G'(2)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{4h+h^2}{h}f(c)$$ for some $c$ between $4$ and $4+4h+h^2$. Thus as $h\to 0$ we have $c\to 4$ and by continuity of $f$ we obtain $G'(2)=4f(4)$.

---

**Note**: The above method is typically used to prove the fundamental theorem of calculus for continuous functions.

Answer (score 0):

What you found is $\frac{dG}{du}$. But you took $u=x^2$, so by chain rule $$\frac{dG}{dx}=\frac{dG}{du}\frac{du}{dx}=f(x)2x$$

Comment: Yeah that is what I felt, so the answer should be $4f(2)$ (I think) but I am not sure how to fix the problem. I know this has to do with integration by substitution.

Comment: You actually didn't substitute inside the integral. Note that the integrable is dependant on $t$ which renassaince as it is. Only the bound of the integral was dependant on $x$ that you substituted by $u$.

Comment: I understand, but I don't quite know how to write it up formally. That is I don't see how to derive it using the definition of derivative alone.